# Extracting URL from text file in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, url, find

I have a script that needs to extract a YouTube URL from a text file.

Here's what I have in the text file (output.txt):

```
  ---------- NUMBER11.TXT
              
<link itemprop="url" href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnxGkOGNMqQEUMvroOWps6Q">
```

Note the text file has a line of empty space to start, which is annoying, and the URL is on line 3. Something that doesn't show up in the formatting for this site is the 11 spaces before the actual `href` starting as well. I'd like to separate it from the mass of other junk.

I've tried something like this:

```
set /p long= < output.txt
echo %long%

set short1=%long:^<link itemprop^="url" href^="=%
echo %short1% > o1.txt
```

I thought this would remove the selected text from the file, but I think this is a little over my head.

I'm getting the `output.txt` from firstly a curl of a youtube video page, and secondly from a `find` command here:

```
find "href=""http://www.youtube.com/channel/" %vd% > output.txt
```

Maybe I'm making this more complicated than it is?

Comment: Change `%vd%` in your `find` command line to `< %vd%`, `< "%vd%"`,  `0< %vd%` or `0< "%vd%"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using batch-files to access files with special characters, like redirect, it can cause some problems, so it is not recommended, but I felt like posting an answer anyway, so given you exact example, here is one way. If your example is not as per your post, which I highly expect it to be, then this probably would not work.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("output.txt") do for %%a in (%%i) do (
    set "var=%%~a"
    set "var=!var:>=!"
    set "var=!var:"=!"
    if "!var:~0,4!" == "http" echo !var!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q64572433.txt"

set "url="
FOR /f "tokens=4,5delims=>= " %%a IN (%filename1%) DO if "%%~a"=="href" set "url=%%~b"

echo URL=%url%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q64572433.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The `for` command tokenises each line of the file, using `=`, `>` and <kbd>space</kbd> as delimiters (the 3 characters between `delims=` and `"`)

On the line of interest, token 4 would be `href` and token 5 the url - and this is the *only* line where `href` is the fourth token. When that is detected, assign the 5th token (in `%%b`) to the variable, removing the quotes with `~` for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you parse the results directly from your `curl` command instead of outputting them to a text file, and then using `find` against that output.

However, instead of using `find.exe`, I would suggest you use the following method using `findstr.exe` instead, *to get the URL assigned to any line containing `href=` followed by `"http:` or `"https` and subsequently followed by `youtube.com`.*

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F Tokens^=*EOL^= %%G In (
    '%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /IR "href=\"http[s:].*youtube\.com" "output.txt"'
) Do (Set "Line=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%H In ("!Line:*href=!") Do EndLocal & Echo %%H)
Pause
```

If you want the output stored as a variable, instead of `Echo`ing it, change `Echo %%H` to `Set "URL=%%H"`. You could then use `%URL%`, *(or `"%URL%"` if you need it doublequoted)*, elsewhere in your script.